# Python/OpenCV: Using cv2.resize() I get an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm using python 2.7 and opencv.

I'm trying to use:

```
cv2.resize(src, dst, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR);
```

taken from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize). But when I run this code I get `NameError: global name 'Size' is not defined.`

Can you help me please?

Comment: you need to provide a destination size args to `Size`: `cv2.resize(src, dst, Size(100,100), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR);` for instance

Comment: @EdChum But in the documentation it says `// specify fx and fy and let the function compute the destination image size.`

Comment: yes I just realised this you should be using the python signature: `cv2.resize(src, dsize[, dst[, fx[, fy[, interpolation]]]]) → dst` see Zdar's answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking at the C++ api of `resize` method.

The python API looks something like this:

```
dst = cv2.resize(src, dsize)
```

where

```
src - Original image
dsize - a tuple defining the final size of the image.
```

If you want to pass additional parameters then you may use the named parameters of the API as:

```
dst = cv2.resize(src, dsize, fx = 0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Since dsize is required param but if you still want the `resize` method to calculate the `dsize` for you then you may pass the param as `None`.

```
dst = cv2.resize(src, None, fx = 0.5, fy=0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it! The issue resulted because I did not use `None` in `Size()`.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer was OK, but I wanted to reuse storage--to resize `image` to fit into existing storage `resized` (both 3-dimensional `uint8` numpy arrays), I needed to use

```
ret = cv2.resize(image, dsize=resized.shape[:2][::-1], dst=resized)
```

Note that the dsize argument is backwards--it's not (rows, columns), but (width, height), hence the `[::-1]`.

I return `ret` only to confirm that indeed `(ret == resized).all()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# lets doubled the size of our image/ increasing the size...
img_double_scaled = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = 1.5, fy = 1.5, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While your code may be helpful, you need to clearly explain how it answers the question.  The OP's question relates to why their code produces a 'NameError" for `Size`. You do not seem to address this in your answer.